# How do I get the amount of XML elements and use it in Quartz Composer?

Tags: xml, quartz-composer

I have a Quartz Composer document which I'm trying to edit but since this is my first dive into QC, I have little to no clue what I'm doing.
The task could be simple: There is an XML Importer and an Iterator. Now I want to use the amount of elements in the imported XML as amount of Iterations.
Can anyone help me achieve this??
Thanks,
thomas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`XML Importer` outputs a QC Structure.  There are a few built-in operations you can perform on Structures, such as the `Structure Count` patch.

If you want to count the number of XML elements inside the top level, feed `XML Importer` into `Structure Count`, and feed that into `Iterations`.

Inside the iterator, you'll probably want to feed `Index` from `Iterator Variables` into the `Structure Index Member` patch, to extract one element of the Structure for each iteration.